# Let $z=\frac{\pi }{2}$, $w=i\pi \in \mathbb {C}$ What is the value of $\cos(z+w)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

This is a question in an online complex analysis course I am taking, but I can't seem to get the right answer, the furtherest I've gotten is

$$\frac{e^{\frac{\pi }{2}+i\pi }+e^{-i\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+i\pi \right)}}{2},$$

can't figure out a solution, would be grateful for any help ( as you can see, I love math, but it is not mutuial).

Comment: What is the value of $e^{\iota \pi}$ and $e^{\iota \frac{\pi}{2}}$? Also, what is the property of multiplication of two exponentials?

Comment: Your first term requires multiplication by $i$ in the exponent.  From there, should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + w \right)=-\sin w.$$

So, $$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + i\pi \right)=-\sin i\pi = -i \sinh \pi = -\frac{i}{2} \left( e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi} \right). $$

Comment: The clearest answer sofar, thanks to all of, you

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ e^{ix} =\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

and $$ e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix}\cdot e^{iy}.$$

Form here you can get the answer .

Answer (score 0):

The law of exponents $e^{w+z}=e^we^z$ holds when $w$ and $z$ are complex numbers.  Also, $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$.  Applying these two rules gives $$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\frac{\pi }{2}+i\pi }+e^{-i\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+i\pi \right)}}{2}&=\frac12\left(e^{\pi/2}e^{i\pi}+e^{\pi}e^{-i\pi/2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{e^{\pi/2}}2-i\frac{e^{\pi}}2
\end{align}$$